# What is the meaning of the letters "O.M.P." for Canon lenses?

Tags: lens, canon, terminology

What do the cryptic letters "o.m.p." mean for a Canon lens? For example, EF 24-105mm f/4L IS USM O.M.P."

Comment: Where are you seeing that? I don't see that on the Canon websites, so it looks like a retailer's acronym.

Comment: It usually means "original manufacturer's packaging" on used equipment sites.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Hadn't encountered that before.

Comment: It is in LL Lozeau.com website

Comment: It is not sell as used

Comment: It may be a returned item, sold, but not actually (or very lightly) used.

Answer (score 4):

It is not really a Canon term as much as it is an abbreviation often used on lists of used photo gear. It is shorthand for "Original Manufacturer Packaging" indicating everything in the original box when new is still with the lens.

Depending on the exact piece of equipment it could include such items as: The box itself, any instruction manuals or guides, software discs, internal plastic wrappers and other packing materials, lens caps & covers, hoods, straps, battery chargers, battery, AV cables, etc.